# Hot Corners modifier key

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, hot-corners

Is there any way of enabling a modifier key to enable Hot Corners?

Some times I accidentally move my mouse to a corner, like when I want to exit full screen of a video, or close a window etc.

It would be a great feature if I could hold in ALT and only then hot corner behavior will trigger.

I haven't found a way of doing this natively, but maybe someone has a script or workaround to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a possibility to trigger selectively. However as a workaround, you could use a custom command that would start by checking if the alt key is held down and trigger the action if and only if…